# As per IEEE 12207, who has to perform SW integration testing?

Tags: integration-tests, sdlc

As per [IEEE 12207](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_12207), who has to perform Software integration testing (SOIPL): SW Testing team or SW Development team?

Comment: could you quote how exactly the standard defines SOIPL? if definition of integration testing is similar to [one in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) then the answer is testing team; if defined differently though, the answer may be opposite

Comment: Mil specs have pros and cons, but have probably helped us in many areas.  We may have learned a few things about software lifecycle models and testing since the specification was created, although its prescriptions should not be ignored without the substitution of good alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The **TL;DR;** answer is "It depends..."

ISO/IEEE 12207 doesn't specify *teams* as such, simply the processes to be followed.  Depending on the nature of the activity (and other requirements, eg DO-178, IEC61508) which introduce requirements for independence at the higher levels, then a single person **can** be responsible for the whole life-cycle.

In simple terms, the *Software Integration Process* (of which integration testing is a part) builds all the (unit tested) modules into a single executable. The stages of the process will be as follows:

- Build manager (or automated process, eg Jenkins) fetches files from Configuration Control tool, and builds the build
- Integration tester(s) then test that build

In a small project, the integration tester(s) may well be the same software engineer(s) who wrote the code... if you have separate teams, I suggest that start of the *Software Integration Process* is probably a good handover point, because thereafter you are testing a full build, probably on target hardware. But that is a local decision to be made.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your reply. As for as system integration testing, i guess it is test team responsibility, to test different entities that make up that system and how they communicate or interact with each other. Where as in case of SW integration testing it is the data flow between two modules are checked. Am i right? If yes, then this testing shall fall on dev team responsibility right. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: @Mahendar you might be interested in studying related questions: [Should a developer also act as a tester?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/102507/31260) and [Functional testing must be done by external party to avoid bias?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/100637/31260)